# IntelliJ - Resolve Maven dependency from a source project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have two Maven Modules loaded in the same IntelliJ project. One module has a dependency on the other one. If I change the version of it, then my second module can't resolve the dependency anymore, except I explicitly run a `mvn install` first.

Can IntelliJ not resolve Maven dependencies from source modules when modules are loaded within the same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm stupid, with correctly group and artifact ids .... works much better !